# How to Deal with Qle_bool in the progress of proving in Coq

Tags: coq

I want to prove the following theorem in Coq.

Please give me an advice if possible.

```
From mathcomp Require Import all_ssreflect.

Require Import QArith.

Theorem Compare_rationals (q1 : Q) (q2 : Q) : 
(if Qle_bool q1 q2 then 1 else 0) == 0 \/
(if Qle_bool q1 q2 then 1 else 0) == 1.
Proof.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may do a case analysis on `Qle_bool q1 q2`:

```
Proof. by case (Qle_bool q1 q2) ; [right | left]. Qed.
```